# How to redirect from index page to other page

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-v4

How can I redirect by loading the page from localhost:xxxx/#/ to localhost:xxxx/#/month ?

I have such index.js code, that calling App class:

```
ReactDOM.render((
    <HashRouter>
        <Route path="/" component={App}>
        </Route>
    </HashRouter>
), document.getElementById('root'));
```

App.js has static information and in component View will be dynamic information:

```
export default class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        Hello App)
        <View/>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

View.js:

```
export default class View extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return(
                <div>
                    <p>this is View</p>
                    <ul>
                        <li><Link to="/month">Month</Link></li>
                        <li><Link to="/week">Week</Link></li>
                        <li><Link to="/day">Day</Link></li>
                        <li><Link to="/year">Year</Link></li>
                    </ul>
                    <Switch>
                        <Route exact path="/month" component={Month} />
                        <Route path="/week" component={Week} />
                        <Route path="/day" component={Day} />
                        <Route path="/year" component={Year} />
                    </Switch>
                </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [Redirect](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Redirect).

```
<Route exact path={your_root_path} render={() => <Redirect to={month_path} />} />
```